# Trouble with DeviceNetworkInformation class

Tags: windows-phone-7, networking

Good morning,

I have to use the properties from DeviceNetworkInformation in my application.

> (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.net.networkinformation.devicenetworkinformation(v=vs.92).aspx)

I've already add the following line to my code

```
using Microsoft.Phone.Net.NetworkInformation;
```

but when I try to use DeviceNetworkInformation, I got the following error:

```
The name "DeviceNetworkInformation" doesn't exist in current context.
```

I just don't know what to do.
Thank you all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's only available for the Windows Phone 7.1 SDK (or newer). You probably made a 7.0 application.

Comment: Thanks! if anyone needs to change to version 7.1:
- right click on project name in solution explorer;
- Click over Properties
- Use the ckeckbox in: "Target Windows Phone OS Version"